# How to test if sorting by dates on a web page is working fine

Tags: java, selenium, sorting, testing

I am automating some features on a web application using selenium and java. One of the pages on the web application list documents and they can be sorted by clicking on two options "Most Recent" that shows the documents uploaded recently on top. I am writing test case to verify if this sorting is working fine. How to verify if the documents are infact sorted in that order. The list shows only the document name and message like  "Uploaded about 2 hrs ago" , "Uploaded 1 day ago", if I capture this message in to a list , is there a way to compare these two and make sure the one that gets displayed on top is recent. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is and what your expected outcome would be. Please create a "Minimal & Reproducible Example" as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the message is fixed like: *x* hrs ago, *x* days ago, *x* weeks ago, etc.

Then you can write a method to convert this time to the lowest possible unit of the application.

For example, if the lowest possible unit is minutes, then write a method that takes 2 parameters (one number and one unit).

Example #1:

```
Input: (2, "hrs")
Output: 120
```

Example #2:

```
Input: (1, "day")
Output: 1440
```

Just a bunch of if-else statements can do the job for you and then it will be easier to sort them.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by RobertBain, you will need to know all the possible units beforehand.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by pcalkins, you can also have a map (key-value store) to define the units like ("day", 1440), etc.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: This seems like a good approach. It's worth mentioning, you'll need to have a look at the source code to get every possible message format.

Comment: in addition you could create key/value pairs for the various strings stored in a map:  key: "day" / value: 1440, etc... this would avoid case switching or if-elses

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out RobertBain, I have updated the answer.
Absolutely pcalkins, having a map will definitely help.

Comment: @Harshal Parekh Thank you for this suggestion, I have automated scenario based on this approach and it is working fine. @ Robert Bain, Thanks for suggesting to look at every possibility, was able to figure out all possible units,  this helped in writing test case that ran fine in all the scenarios.

Comment: Glad to hear. Good luck.